# I have a View with three form tags. How do I go about processing each form separately in the controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC and am having trouble with a more complicated form than most examples, that I've seen.
The View is structured in three sections, which are actually forms.
My question is about passing a model and processing of these forms.
A colleague of mine suggested using three controllers for each form.
But then how do I pass a separate model to each form?
I think you get the idea.
Would you please help me with this task?

Comment: please share some code.

Comment: I'm not ready to share code, as I think it would be too much for this question. I'll try to do that tomorrow. For now I would be glad to get some ideas about solving this.

Comment: You can use multiple forms in one `view` but each view will corresponds to their own `ActionMethod` in controller.

Comment: How do I pass different models to each form?

Comment: Do not pass model to form. Use the `name` property of `input` elements as `Model property name`. When the form posted it will get value by using the `name` property.

Comment: So the View will have one model, but I would like to update just the form, in which the corresponding Submit button was clicked. I think I am going to get NullReferenceExceptions from the other forms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219835/discussion-between-eis-karlsson-and-abdul-haseeb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say we have 3 `models`

```
Public class Model1
{
    public string name{get;set;}
}
Public class Model2
{
    public string name{get;set;}
}
Public class Model3
{
    public string name{get;set;}
}
```

Then we have a three form in a `view`. and each `form` corresponds to their own `ActionMethod` that you specify in the `first` parameter in `Html.BeginForm`

```
@Html.BeginForm("Model1Action","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post)
{
    //dont use @Model.Name in the name property of input element.
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
}
@Html.BeginForm("Model12Action","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post)
{
    //dont use @Model.Name in the name property of input element.
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
}
@Html.BeginForm("Model3Action","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post)
{
    //dont use @Model.Name in the name property of input element.
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
}
```

Then in the controller Action method

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult Model1Action(Model1 obj)
{
    Response.Write(obj.name);
}
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult Model1Action(Model1 obj)
{
    Response.Write(obj.name);
}
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult Model1Action(Model1 obj)
{
    Response.Write(obj.name);
}
```

Comment: @Html.BeginForm is kind of obsolete in asp.net core

Comment: In the View, how do you pass all three models?

Comment: Also in the Action methods, how do you return the View - return View(obj) would use just one model?

Comment: @EisKarlsson don't create the `HttpGet` method of an `Action` use only `HttpPost` method.